# CKEDITOR : Set scroll event to CKEditor Document

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I'm trying to set `scroll event` to CKEditor.

I try the below things to get this done.

**Methode 1:**

```
var html = $(editor.editable().$);
$(html).on('scroll',function(){
   console.log('Scroll');
});
```

**Methode 2:**

```
editor.on('scroll',function(){
    console.log('Scroll');
});
```

But both the methods are not working very well.

Any Suggestions.Please Help me.

Comment: Are you sure about `$(editor.editable().$);` ? What is `$` at end

Comment: It's getting the Html value of Editable area.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the Answer.

```
editor.document.on('scroll',function(){
     console.log('scroll Works');
});
```